# New custom post type entries are not sorted correctly in admin using pre_get_posts

Tags: query, sort, pre-get-posts

I am working on a WordPress plugin and trying to use the `pre_get_posts` hook. Everything seems to sort, but when I add new items through the back-end, they get added to the bottom and not sorted for some reason. Hoping a fresh set of eyes could help.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'simple_class_custom_query' );

function simple_class_custom_query ( $query ) {
    // Sort Archive Page Results
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'simple_class' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Sort results by class day
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'class-day' );

        // orderby class start
        $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'class-start' => 'ASC' ) );

        // Hide hidden classes
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'hide-class',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! Should add this has a few pieces. The `hide-class` is a meta checkbox to hide the class and the classes should be sorted by the day of the week the class takes place and then by start time.

Comment: The code posted would not affect the back end since the `is_post_type_archive( 'simple_class' )` check will return false in the admin. So, some other code/plugin may be affecting the admin area.

Comment: ..unless this is part of file that is loaded in admin only.

Comment: Show us the `meta_value`. Is it `on`/`off`. Is it `1` / `0` ?

Comment: Perhaps I should be using meta_value_num. It's a range from 1 to 7, corresponding to a day of the week. This is for the front end of the site and not the admin area.

What's happening here (or at least should be) is to sort classes by date and then by start time.

Comment: Ok. That `is_post_type_archive( 'simple_class' )` is the problem as I'm using this on a page through a shortcode. So none of the query items are actually being run.